# How to get SVN Repository linked to Jenkins Job.?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

Is there a way to get the Jenkins Job using Jenkins-cli jar or Jenkins xml/json api.?

I do have a way to fetch it from last successful build call. But, i am thinking of a job that does not have any build. I tried using get-job option with jenkins-cli, but it is throwing exception saying, i do not have extensive read permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the entire job configuration via `http://jenkins:8080/job/jobnameE/config.xml`.

Look for the `scm` node inside the XML document. You find the repository in `scm/locations/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation/remote`.

An example `scm` node looks like this:

```
<scm class="hudson.scm.SubversionSCM" plugin="subversion@2.5.1">
    <locations>
        <hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation>
            <remote>http://source/svn/MyProject/trunk</remote>
            <credentialsId>74fc995c-2005-4b6e-9911-f231995b48bb</credentialsId>
            <local>MyProject</local>
            <depthOption>infinity</depthOption>
            <ignoreExternalsOption>false</ignoreExternalsOption>
        </hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation>
        <hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation>
            <remote>http://source/svn/OtherProject/trunk</remote>
            <credentialsId>74fc995c-2005-4b6e-9911-f231995b48bbc</credentialsId>
            <local>OtherProject</local>
            <depthOption>infinity</depthOption>
            <ignoreExternalsOption>false</ignoreExternalsOption>
        </hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation>
    </locations>
    <excludedRegions/>
    <includedRegions/>
    <excludedUsers/>
    <excludedRevprop/>
    <excludedCommitMessages/>
    <workspaceUpdater class="hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater" />
    <ignoreDirPropChanges>false</ignoreDirPropChanges>
    <filterChangelog>false</filterChangelog>
</scm>
```

In case you need authentication then you should read this:
[Authenticating scripted clients](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients).

Comment: Thank you. However, to access this url authentication is required. How could i get the data in xml from command line using curl.? have you tried it that way.?